# How do I show tasks from only one project in a solution in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a solution in VS2013 that has multiple projects, one of which is code from a library which I don't often contribute to but I frequently pull from a repo. I'm looking for a way to show "//TODO" comments in the Task List from only the project I'm currently working on.

As it stands, the task list is inundated with //TODOs that other people are working on. My workaround is to name all of my personal TODOs as //JOB, but even being able to view just one project's //JOBs at a time would be a big plus and would prevent me needing to invent new comment names for each project I have in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2103 doesn't contain this functionally and some people requested this feature in MSDN VS blog.

You can extend VS2013 with Resharper that has a nice ToDo explorer.

Have a look here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Windows__To-do_Explorer.html

You can group your TODOs by namespaces or projects for example...

Let me know if that supports you question.

Comment: That works, thanks. I'm guessing that since JetBrains managed it, it should be possible for me to write a custom extension that could supply this functionality?

Comment: True, but hey - why bother when jet brain doing an awesome job ;)

Comment: Just a little matter of $149 :)

Comment: Indeed. but you get pretty a-lot on them. actually I can't imagine coding life before...